# TASM write to stdout vs write to file behaviour difference when using print macro

Tags: assembly, file-io, tasm

This is my macro for writing to STDOUT:

```
; print string (immediate): ex. m_puts "hello!"
m_puts macro string
local @@start, @@data
      push ax dx
      push ds
      jmp short @@start     ; string is being stored
@@data db string,'$'        ; in the code segment
@@start:                    ; so skip over it
      mov  ax,cs
      mov  ds,ax       ; set DS to code segment
      mov  ah,9
      lea  dx, [@@data]
      int  21h
      pop  ds          ; restore registers
      pop dx ax
endm
```

it writes to CS and reads from it (by using DS temporarily to point to CS), writing what it had read to STDOUT.

Usage example:
`m_puts 'hello world!'`

Now I'm making minor changes to write to a file instead:

```
m_puts_to_file macro string
local @@start, @@data
      push ax cx dx
      push ds
      jmp short @@start     ; string is being stored
@@data db string            ; in the code segment
@@start:                    ; so, skip over it
      mov  ax,cs
      mov  ds,ax            ; set DS to code segment
      mov  ah,40h
      mov  bx, file_out_handle
      mov  cx, si      ; how many bytes to write
      lea  dx, [@@data]
      int  21h
      pop  ds          ; restore registers
      pop dx cx ax
endm
```

Where `file_out_handle` is a word in memory.

However, nothing is written to a file after running:

```
mov si, 12
m_puts_to_file 'hello world!'
```

If I define `'hello world!'` directly in data segment, without using the macro, writing to a file works.

What could be the case here and how could I troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> mov  ax,cs
>  mov  ds,ax            ; set DS to code segment
>  mov  ah,40h
>  mov  bx, file_out_handle
> ```

Your *file_out_handle* variable sits in the `DS` segment, but you're reading it **after you have changed `DS` to point to `CS`**.
Move the `mov  bx, file_out_handle` higher up in the code.